# Which kinds of priors could be applied in Bayesian linear regression?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, bayesian, overfitting, bayesian-optimization

I would like to know can we use any kind of prior distribution in Bayesian linear regression and still convergent to a close mean solution to the Least square solution? Or it should be just a conjugate prior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two separate issues:

- Choice of priors; when the priors are symmetric about zero (except for the intercept) and have wide dispersion you'll see pretty good agreement with least squares estimates (but see the next point)
- How do you look at the Bayesian posterior distributions for parameters?  Bayes takes uncertainties into account and does not invite you to oversimplify parameters into single number summaries.  If you want a single number summary of a posterior distribution you need to decide on a loss function, and as a result you'll get things like posterior means, posterior medians, posterior modes, ...  In general the posterior mode is most similar to traditional maximum likelihood estimates (of which least squares is an example, if residuals are Gaussian)

So it's not a very simple question.  A very rough answer is that you'll see similar when using wide prior distributions and force yourself to distill the posterior distribution into the posterior mode (the parameter value that maximizes the posterior density).

Comment: Thank you @Frank. So, to verify that I understand well if we can use a symmetric prior about zero, such as normal distribution, gamma inverse, Laplace distribution, or uniform distribution still we can get a close estimate to OLS? Even it does not need to be exactly conjugate?

Comment: Almost.   The prior has to also be wide.  One way to understand this: if using a normal prior with mean zero and very large variance, the posterior mode will approximate the MLE.  If the variance is small it will approximate the penalized MLE (ridge regression) with coefficients shrunken towards zero.